# Need task to ignore schedule

Tags: ms-project

I have a situation where we will be doing a conversion over a weekend in order to minimize impact to the company. Additionally, this task should be delayed until 3 weeks after a predecessor task. What are some ways to handle both of these together?

- I have indicated that this task should use the 24 hour calendar
- I have indicated that this task should ignore the resource calendar
- In doing so, I have had to indicate that the lag from the predecessor needs to be 2 months in order to get the date of the subsequent task pushed out 3 weeks.

Is there a way to keep from having to use the 2 month lag? The date ends up right, but my OCD starts twitching for having to indicate 2 months for a 3 week spread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duration of the lag should be expressed in elapsed days. Change the lag to 21ed to get the task to start 21 "calendar" days after the predecessor, regardless of non-working time. The duration of the task itself could also be expressed in elapsed days if necessary.

[Here's a quick primer on elapsed days.](http://epmainc.com/blog/elapsed-days-microsoft-project)